# How to query range of numbers in cosmosdb?

Tags: sql, azure-cosmosdb

I have looked at the cosmosdb docs and have followed the docs for doing a `between` query. [cosmos query docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-keywords)  I am trying to do a simple query to get a result that includes all objects created in between 2 dates. The dates are represented as unix time stamps. The data does exist in the table, but the results return 0. The query looks like this.

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.createdDate BETWEEN 1583280000 AND 1596124706
```

The json object format of the objects that I expect to be returned is:

```
{
"id": "70aef223-7af6-4014-86f7-ab24f5c2f6ee",
"createdDate": 1582500694038,
"updatedDate": 1584401494038
...
}
```

Does anybody know how to do a query between 2 dates which are represented as unix timestamps as shown in the above query?

Comment: Please share an example of the item JSON from your Cosmos container?

Comment: @NoahStahl I updated the question to include the format of the object I expect to be returned. The object is much bigger that what is there but i felt those fields were irrelevant so I added the `...` Thank you

Comment: Thanks, it looks correct to me. Are you seeing this with that raw query, or using an SDK? If SDK, what's the query code look like?

Comment: @NoahStahl this is in the data explorer in the azure console. Specifically I click on the button New SQL query. I type the query in there.

Comment: Hmm, it should work as far as I can see....

Comment: Ahh super dumb on my part ... The year was corrupted on the range that I was trying to query but was correct on the areas of the data. So it was my mistake. Thank you for your input @NoahStahl

Comment: No problem! Consider deleting the question if no actual issue.

Comment: @Dan Thanks for Noah Stahl's help! We are glad that you find the issue and resolved it. I just help you post it as the answer.  You could think about mark it as as answer and  don't need delete the question. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.